# Deploy Windows 7 Backup set to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, backup, restore

Situation:

We have a laptop here that's completely fubar. I.e: The hard drive is filled to the brim with bad sectors. Luckily, backups have been made using the built-in Windows 7 backup feature. This produces folders named `Backup Set 2012-11-09 003009`, containing folders like `Backup Files 2012-11-09 003009`, containing zip-files like `Backup files 1, 2, 3,...`

Our brand new laptop comes with Windows 8. Now: Can we, using the standard back-up and restore feature in Windows 8, restore all the documents, music, etc. using the Windows 7 backup files?
Thanks.

(FYI: We also took a normal backup of all the documents just to be sure of course. I'm just curious what would happen. I would test it out, but the new laptop hasn't arrived yet and I wanted to make sure my efforts would not be in vain.)

Comment: How did you made the backup, did you used the inbuilt option for that or manually ?

Comment: The inbuilt option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Start Screen, type "recovery" to search, click the **Settings** category and open **Windows 7 File Recovery**:

[image: 1]

You may need to click **Select another backup to restore files from** on the file recovery screen to access your backup files:

[image: 2]

Comment: Does not appear not work in Windows 8.1 (non pro) (there simply is no "Windows 7 File Recovery" under the control panel -- german Win 8.1 OEM)

Comment: [No longer on Windows 8.1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1c7e14d9-2fd3-46bd-a6eb-a7d8ce2f1b4f/cant-restore-windows-7-file-backup-in-windows-81)