# How to recover Firefox and Chrome bookmarks after upgrade from Windows Vista to 8

Tags: firefox, windows-8, google-chrome, windows-vista, windows-backup

I upgraded a laptop from Windows Vista to 8, doing a format & re-install first.  Before the format, I used both Windows Backup and Easy Transfer (7) first.  I imported the user accounts into Windows 8 using Windows Easy Transfer.  I installed Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, and neither have my old bookmarks!

It seems that Windows Easy Transfer is too selective to include those other bookmarks.  My only hope is if those browser data files were include in Windows Backup.  The Vista version of Backup implements the backup as a bunch of ZIP files.

1. Do you think the bookmark files are in the Windows Backup files, or did Microsoft decide that a backup doesn't "need" to be comprehensive?
2. There are several hundred ZIP files in the backup.  Is there a way to search the backup for my bookmarks besides several months of manual inspection?

Comment: You should be able to launch [File Recovery in Win8](http://superuser.com/a/519123/138343) and browse for files after selecting your backup location.

Comment: I saw that option a few minutes after posting by poking around some more.  I copied the Chrome folder, renamed the folder created by the new install first.  Chrome ignored my attempt, acting as a virgin install!  Switching the folders back worked just fine.

Comment: **Chrome:** `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks` (restore this file and *Bookmarks.bak* manually), **Firefox:** `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ProfileName\bookmarkbackups\*.json` (can be imported from within Firefox via *Ctrl+Shift+B / Import and Backup / Restore / Choose File*).

Answer (score -1):

Add google account to chrome and your bookmarks will be synced with google account. After installing new chrome add account first and chrome will download your bookmarks and extensions automatically from the account. For Firefox you can use [Xmarks addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/).